# Using productontology in Schema.org for another language?

Tags: language, schema.org, productontology.org

I have a site that is in two languages, German and English. For each version of the site I am defining different schema.org markups. For example, the descriptions provided are in German or English depending on the domain (I am using subdomains for each language.)

Specifying different schemas hasn't been an issue until I went to add productontology to one of them. Here is the issue:

This is the productontology for the English site:

```
http://www.productontology.org/id/Wine_bar
```

The German equivalent is:

```
http://www.productontology.org/id/Vinothek
```

Here is the issue I foresee, and would like to know the best way to handle it. The first productontology, `Wine_bar` is correct, however, if you access `Vinothek` on the *English* wikipedia it has a different meaning than the German wikipedia.

This leads me to my question: What is the best way to handle productontology for a different language?

In my case, should I use `Wine_bar` for both languages?

While reading the [productontology website](http://www.productontology.org/) I saw [an faq](http://www.productontology.org/#faq3) that specifically stated this:

> ... Wikipedia entry in the **English(!)** ...

The `English(!)` is bolded on that page, not by me. Since I read this I assume I should use the English wikipedia page regardless of the language.

Am I correct? What is the best way to handle productontology for other languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that [`http://www.productontology.org/id/Vinothek`](http://www.productontology.org/id/Vinothek) works (it redirects to [`http://www.productontology.org/id/Enoteca`](http://www.productontology.org/id/Enoteca)) is not because it’s called "Vinothek" in German, but because the English Wikipedia has a redirect from [Vinothek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinothek) to [Enoteca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enoteca).

The PTO only [uses the terms from the English Wikipedia](http://www.productontology.org/#about):

> You can use this ontology to describe any object for which a matching entry in the English Wikipedia exists.

So you should use [`pto:Wine_bar`](http://www.productontology.org/id/Wine_bar) or [`pto:Enoteca`](http://www.productontology.org/id/Enoteca) (whichever applies in your case) for the English as well as the German page.

Comment: What unor says is correct. www.productontology.org operates on the conceptual level and takes the English Wikipedia lemmata as the orientation. The translations given for other languages are just approximations and based on the links to other language versions in Wikipedia. It may thus be that the translated labels in PTO do not represent the exact meaning. The English description is authoritative in case of doubt.